# django-logpipe (kafka) implementation in django project

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement django-logpipe into my Django project.

My goal is to organize requests from rest_framework.viewsets to the database into a queue, using kafka (indirectly by django-logpype).

Using [wemake-django-template](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template) as start point for my project, i successfully install 'django-logpipe' package and launch it, using [this tutorial.](https://pypi.org/project/django-logpipe/) Migration

```
python manage.py migrate logpipe
```

was successfull.

This is my project hirerarchy:

```
bills
  config
  docker
  docs
  locale
  server
    apps
      ...
      bill
        migrations
        static
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        forms.py
        managers.py
        models.py
        permissions.py
        router.py
        serializers.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
      ...
```

I've all ready made serilizars modification for django-logpipe. My next step: Producers and Consumers.

As far as i could understand, according [tutorial](https://pypi.org/project/django-logpipe/), i can implement Consumers of django-loppipe in apps.py by this:

```
# bills/server/apps/bill/apps.py
from logpipe import Consumer, register_consumer
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BillConfig(AppConfig):
     name: str
     name = 'bill'

# Register consumers with logpipe
@register_consumer
def build_person_consumer():
    consumer = Consumer('people')
    consumer.register(PersonSerializer)
    return consumer
```

But, where i can put Producer?
As far as i understand, Producer should send a JSON data to Consumer, which should serialize it in apropriate data structure and process it by registred serializer. Data i can receive from Django it self, and from rest api.

First place in rest_framework.viewsets where i can see a data from api is a get_serializer from my BillViewSet:

```
class BillViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    queryset = Bill.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BillModelSerializer
    read_serializer_class = BillReadSerializer
    write_serializer_class = BillWriteSerializer
    scan_write_serializer_class = BillScanWriteSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                        EditAuthority,
                        IsProperStatus]

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get', 'post', 'put'])
    def image(self, request):
        ...

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        ...

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs) -> serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer:
        result = None
        if self.request.method in ['GET']:
            if hasattr(self, 'read_serializer_class'):
                kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
                result = self.read_serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
        elif (self.request.method in ['POST', 'PUT']) and ('data' in kwargs):
            if hasattr(self, 'write_serializer_class'):
                if isinstance(kwargs['data'], QueryDict):
                        buf = [k.replace('null', 'None') for k in kwargs['data'].keys()]
                        buf = [eval(i) for i in buf]
                        if self.request.method in ['POST']:
                            p_data = buf[0]['data']['0']  # type : Dict[str, Any] = List[Dict[str, Dict[Union[int, slice], Any]]
                        elif self.request.method in ['PUT']:
                            buf = list(buf[0]['data'].values())
                            p_data = buf[0]  # type : Dict[str, Union[int, str]]
                elif isinstance(kwargs['data'], Dict):
                    p_data = kwargs['data']
                kwargs['data'] = self.prepare_data(p_data, remove_none=False)
                kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
                result = self.write_serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
        if not result:
            result = super().get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
        return result

    def get_options(self) -> Tuple[str, Dict[str, List[Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]]]:
        ...

    def prepare_data(self,
                    data: Dict[str, Union[int, str]],
                    remove_none: bool = True) -> Dict[str, Union[int, str]]:
        if 'action' in data and data['action'] == 'upload':
            return data
        else:
            buf = {}  # buf : Dict[str, Union[int, str]]
            fields_for_eval = ['supplier',
                            'nds_tax',
                            'category',
                            'status',
                            'user']
            fields_for_float = ['amount', 'amountNDS', 'amountPURE']
            for key, value in data.items():
                if key in fields_for_eval and isinstance(value, str):
                    buf[key] = eval(value)
                if key in fields_for_float:
                    buf[key] = float(value if value else 0)
                if key in ['scan']:
                    if (not value) or value in ['None', 'null']:
                        buf[key] = None
            for k, v in buf.items():
                if not v and remove_none:
                    data.pop(k)
                else:
                    data[k] = v
            return data

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Bill.objects.all()
        if not self.action == 'destroy':
            queryset = self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(queryset=queryset)
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        datatables_extra_json = ('get_options', )
```

It called from List, Create, Update Mixins, during process 'dispatch' method in ApiView class. First thought was implement Producer in get_serializer method and send data from there, but it pointless, because data would duplicated during processed by standart ViewSets.

I can't use get_serializer at all, without override standard ViewSet Mixins or ApiView - it would break a logic. And i just can't find a simple solution. Which options i have any way?

I think there must be way to make it simple. If django-logpipe allready highly integrated in django, there must be some options.